How to programmatically stop an Amazon Connect CCP user ending ACW state
Is it possible to programmatically stop a CCP agent ending After Call Work (ACW) contact state by either disabling the Close Contact button or cancelling the Close Contact event?
We are using the out of the box Stream API CCP.  We are hosting the CCP in our own website.
We want our agents to complete a number of tasks on the website before they end ACW.  So I want to either

disable the CCP's Close Contact button until the tasks have been completed, or
check that that tasks have been completed when the agent clicks the CCP's Close Contact button and if they have not completed those tasks, then show a message and cancel the CCP Close Contact event.

I realise I can hook into the contact.onACW event, but at the moment I can't cancel it.

I fairly certain you can capture the events from within the CCP itself and you can't alter anything within the CCP iframe. So the only way to do this is to hide the CCP iframe via css e.g.
#container-div iframe {
  display: none;
}

But this means you need to build out all the CCP features you want available. Call state, answer, hold, end call buttons, dial pad if necessary and so on.
Another possibility would be to hide the CCP iframe when the agents goes into ACW and only display it again once they have completed the tasks.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to disable the Close Contact button or cancel the Close Contact event using the out-of-the-box Stream API CCP. These functionalities are tightly controlled by the API.
However, you have a couple of alternatives:

Deploy a Custom CCP and UI: If feasible, you could create your own custom CCP and UI. This would allow you to implement the required checks before ending the ACW (After Call Work) state.

Adjust ACW Timeout: Set the ACW timeout to 0. This forces agents to manually end the ACW state rather than it ending automatically. While this doesn't prevent them from ending ACW prematurely, it does add a manual step.

Monitor with AWS Lambda: Develop an AWS Lambda function that subscribes to contact events via EventBridge. This function can monitor and report instances where ACW was ended without completing all tasks. This way, you can track non-compliance and take corrective action.


Although these alternatives don't provide a direct way to control the CCP's Close Contact button, they offer ways to manage and monitor the ACW process more effectively.
